# Flatpak-Builder cannot find already installed dependency

Tags: flatpak

I wanted to install a flatpak image from source code. Inside the manifest file, it is specified that `rust-stable` is required.

```
"sdk-extensions": [
    "org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.rust-stable"
],
```

The specified Rust flatpak is already installed on my system twice:

```
$ flatpak list|grep Rust
Rust stable org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.rust-stable   1.55.0  20.08   flathub system
Rust stable org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.rust-stable   1.55.0  20.08   flathub user
```

But when I try to build and install the flatpak, it tells me that the `rust-stable` flatpak is not available:

```
$ flatpak-builder --install --force-clean mysoftware com.example.MySoftware.Devel.json

(flatpak-builder:18580): Json-CRITICAL **: 10:37:25.850: json_object_get_string_member: assertion 'node != NULL' failed

(flatpak-builder:18580): flatpak-builder-WARNING **: 10:37:25.850: Missing source type

(flatpak-builder:18580): Json-WARNING **: 10:37:25.851: Failed to deserialize "sources" property of type "gpointer" for an object of type "BuilderModule"
Downloading sources
Initializing build dir
error: Requested extension org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.rust-stable not installed
```

Why doesn't flatpak find the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Zaclegarssure's answer, to install the latest (master branch) flatpak packages probably required, you need to install packages for example from the gnome-nightly repository by

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists gnome-nightly https://nightly.gnome.org/gnome-nightly.flatpakrepo
```

and install a nightly app by

```
flatpak install gnome-nightly org.gnome.Sdk
```

See https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Nightly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already managed to solve it in the meantime, but I don't recall the exact way how to.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't install the right branch of `rust-stable`.
One thing you can do is to add: `--install-deps-from=flathub` to the `flatpak-builder` command, it will automatically download every dependencies, such as runtime and skd-extensions, with the right version.

Hope that helps.

Comment: When I do that, it tries to install `org.gnome.Sdk/x86_64/master`, but ultimately fails to do so: `error: Nothing matches org.gnome.Sdk in remote flathub`.